# How can I write this SQL query? Displaying friends

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a friend system, which handles friend requests and friendships.

I have a table named `Member`  where I keep information about each member including their id, first and last name

and another table named Friendships where I keep track of the id of the first friend `Friend1` and the second `Friend2` and the date of the friendship formation.(Note: each request is recorded twice in my database; ex 1 -> 2 and 2->1 )

I am trying to write a query to display the first and last name of the friends of the current user. I know I have to INNER JOIN both tables, but I am not sure ON what exactly.

Comment: You describe the tables as having a foreign key relationship, so you'd join on that.  The `id` which connects the records in your join point.

Comment: Run this: `show create table TABLENAME` and paste the results in your question

Comment: So your friendship table is something like username,friendFirstName, friendLastName?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the friend table and members table have same ID columns,

```
SELECT m.first, m.second 
FROM m.member INNER JOIN f.friendships
ON f.id = m.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be somthings like this

```
 select a.firstname, b.lastname from Member a 
 inner join Friendships b on (b.friend1_id = a.id ) 
 and a.id = 'current_user_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

On the foreign keys (I guess Members.Id=Friendships.Friend1) but it really depends on the semantics you are implementing with those duplicate (bidirectional?) friendship relations.